# Letting users create customized Bundles in Magento

Tags: php, magento

We are building an e-commerce site where users can create their own bundles with products of their choice. Other users can then buy these bundles.

Please guide me as to how a bundle can be created based on the products selected by user and store this bundle. From whatever little I have read, I can create a module which will do this. Is this the right approach, or is their any other way to do it. I have gone through Alan's post to create modules, but still my magento knowledge is limited.

I am new to magento, and a newbie programmer (hence this is my first post on stackoverflow), any detailed description will greatly help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't a shopping cart a user bundle by definition?

- You can save the order information and create bundled items from that
- Create an administration module that parses the information from orders and chooses automatically the most selected group of packages and creates automatically a product based on that.
- If you want to involve the user that is more work for the CRM than for Magento, allowing the user to create bundle products and save them.

**Update**
From your comments I see 2 ways of solving this issue

1. with the help of the checkout and order object - when a selection is saved.
2. without any connection with the checkout process you'll build a frontend module that will save independently a bunch of products and will transform the selection into a backend bundle product that will be later available to all users. Steps to do towards this approach

   - build the interface to let the user select several products
   - make a save action that will grab the currently selected products from a cookie or somewhere and tranform that in the background in a product.
   - save the product and reindex the site to have the product available

Comment: Yes, that would be one of the ways of doing it. But my customers need not necessarily checkout with the products they just bundled. They must be able to save the bundle.
The following link will make things clear, I guess (I have no idea what that language is)
http://www.stylefruits.de/combine

Comment: Thanks for helping me out elzo, sad that i cannot up-vote, i don't have enough "reputation"...:(..

Comment: Hi Harsha, we are trying to do something similar... here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839790/how-can-we-achieve-custom-designing-feature-using-magento were you able to implement the solution of saving? if you were able to... I would like to get in touch and see if you can help us. Thank you.